# What are the available Report Types when using the VSTS GET Build Report API?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm looking at the VSTS REST API documentation on getting a build report and unable to find the types of reports available using the URI parameter.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/report/get

GET

https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/report?**type={type}**&api-version=4.1-preview.2

Any idea on the available report types?

Comment: Can you get all whole build report by `GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/report?api-version=4.1-preview.2`?

Answer (score 3):

The only supported type is "html".