# How to get TFS build report in PowerShell with REST API

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get the build report with PowerShell script via REST API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/report/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1

```
$PAT = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
# This is required to pass PAT through HTTP header
$script:User = "" # Not needed when using PAT, can be set to anything
$script:Base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User, $PAT)))

$url = "$TfsUri/$TeamProject/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/report?api-version=4.1-preview.2"
$buildReport = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

But I am getting error Requested stream  is not supported for reports

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Requested stream  is not supported for reports.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.ReportStreamNotSupportedE 
xception, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"ReportStreamNotSupportedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At C:\Source\Configurations\Scripts\CheckLastBuild.ps1:76 char:20
+ ... ildReport = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers @{Author ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Invoking the same request with the browser works fine and returns an HTML text with a build report.

What am I doing wrong? The same method is used without any problem to get definitions, builds, releases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following URL parameter:

```
type=html
```

So, in your case:

```
$url = "$TfsUri/$TeamProject/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/report?api-version=4.1-preview.2&type=html"
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Do you know what are the allowed values for this parameter? Documentation does not show any details.

Comment: I don't know but someone answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976217/what-are-the-available-report-types-when-using-the-vsts-get-build-report-api that it's only `html`